# ¿Como obtener el valor de un claim-token en angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net, angularjs

Estoy realizando una aplicación con angular y aspnetcore para la api, estoy tratando de obtener el `name` de la `List<Claim>` para poder mostrarlo en el dashboard cuando inicio sesión con jwt

Este en mi método para crear el token y su estructura:

```
    private string CreateJwt(User user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}")
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        //var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        var jwr = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        return jwr;
    }
```

Esta es la estructura a la hora de desencriptar mi Jwt creado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi servicio del usuario lo tengo de esta forma:

```
export class UserStoreService {

private fullName$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

constructor() { }

public getFullNameFromStore(){
   return this.fullName$.asObservable();
}

public setFullNameFromStore(fullName: string){
  this.fullName$.next(fullName)
}

}
```

En mi authService es de esta:

```
export class AuthService {

private baseUrl: string = "https://localhost:7033/api/User/";
private userPayLoad:any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { 
  this.userPayLoad = this.decodedToken();
}

getFullNameFromToken(){
  if(this.userPayLoad)
  return this.userPayLoad.name;
}

getRoleFromToken(){
  if(this.userPayLoad)
  return this.userPayLoad.role;
}

}
```

Y en mi dashboard html solo lo mando a llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
  <div>
    <h4>Hello, {{fullName}}</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Pero no me trae el nombre del usuario ingresado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe si estoy realizando algo mal, me ayudarian mucho con sus comentarios.